# Como formateo una fecha como este string?

Tags: php, datetime

como puedo formatear una fecha con DateTime para que quede así:

```
2021-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Estoy usando DateTime con PHP

```
$start_date = new DateTime();

$start_date->format('Y-m-dH:i:s') (Necesito que quede el formato de la fecha como el string de arriba)
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Juan, esta es una comunidad hispanohablante, puedes repetir la pregunta en castellano, o formularla en ingés en [la versión en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Si no me di cuenta que estaba en la versión español. Ahora edito la pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el autor de [**ésta respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27792899/17727129), podrías hacerlo con:

```
$start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000+0000');
```

Un ejemplo sería:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$new_date = $start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000+0000');
echo $new_date;
```

**Output:**

```
2022-12-22T16:25:51.000+0000
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! También encontre que se puede formatear de la siguiente manera ->format('c'), cual es la diferencia entre formatear la fecha de esta manera o de la manera que me dijiste vos? Hay alguna diferencia o es lo mismo?

Comment: @JuanSpada recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió marcando al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida. `format->('c')` es similar, solo que defines también los números que están después del `+` dependiendo de la zona horaria que establezcas.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

puedes intentar de esta forma :)

```
$fecha = new DateTime(); // Crea una nueva fecha con la fecha y hora actual
$formato = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z'; // Define el formato de salida deseado
$fechaFormateada = $fecha->format($formato); // Formatea la fecha con el formato deseado

echo $fechaFormateada; // Imprime la fecha formateada: 2021-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! También encontre que se puede formatear de la siguiente manera ->format('c'), cual es la diferencia entre formatear la fecha de esta manera o de la manera que me dijiste vos? Hay alguna diferencia o es lo mismo?

Comment: `c` equivale a una fecha en formato ISO, que es en el que está tu fecha. Está todo explicado en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php). Y, puedes usar el método `createFromFormat` directamente, pasándole la cadena con la fecha y el formato en que está.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

El formato que necesitas es `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000O` la mayoría se puede deducir, pero la T es fija, los .000 también son fijos, y la O añade el uso horario es lo que hace que quede +0000 en la parte final.

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000O');
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, no me quise alargar en la explicación ya que el otro formato que mostraste ya tenia algunos elementos.

Adicional a lo que dije, la T necesita el backslash de no añadirlo mostrara UTC.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!